# Taylor series remainder (Lagrange)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have this function $f(x) = ln(1+x)$ and I want to come up with the Maclaurin series for it up to $n = 3, a = 0$.

I calculate that the remainder $n=3$ is

$R_3(x)=-\frac{6}{4!(1+c)^4}x^4, \; c \in (a, x)$

1. How do I calculate $c$ for the remainder in this case?
2. How do I prove/disprove that $|R_3(x)|<\frac{1}{4}, \; x \in (0; \frac{1}{2}]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Question 2, note that in our interval the remainder has absolute value
$$\frac{6}{4!(1+c)^4}x^4.$$
We have $c\gt 0$, and therefore $(1+c)^4\gt 1$. Thus the remainder has absolute value less than $\frac{6}{4!}x^4$. This is $\frac{1}{4}x^4$.

If we want a *uniform* (independent of $x$) bound for $x$ in the interval $(0,1/2)$, note that $x^4\lt \frac{1}{16}$, giving a uniform bound of $\frac{1}{64}$.

As to Question 1, questions of this type usually we do not have a useful answer. We can *estimate* $c$, but except in a trivial sense we cannot find an **exact** value for $c$. Of course, we have $\ln(1+x)=P_3(x)+R_3(x)$. Thus $R_3(x)=\ln(1+x)-P_3(x)$. Now you can use your formula for $R_3(x)$ to solve for $c$. But for that we need to know $\ln(1+x)$ **exactly**.

Comment: The interval for $x$ is $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$, so this $x^4 \leq \frac{1}{16}$ would be the correct definition?

Comment: I covered that under the *uniform estimate* part of the answer. I assumed that the question was about the Lagrange form of the remainder. When we have an alternating series (as we do in this case if $0\lt x\le 1$), the size of the first "neglected" term gives an easier to use and often better estimate than the Lagrange form.  Estimates based on the Lagrange form are often unduly pessimistic.

Answer (score 1):

You can also derive an error estimate by noticing that the Series is an alternating one and the tail has to be less then the first neglected term which in this case is x^4/4.

Comment: Is that a good approximation generally?

Comment: @Morgan Wilde that works for all alternating series I believe.

Comment: @Morgan Wilde left out the important word convergent, sorry.